# error con forma de incrustar código php con html

Tags: php, html5

estoy realizando la migración de mi codigo de mi localhost a un servidor de desarrollo ambos con la misma versión de php (5.4.16). el problema es que el codigo no esta funcionando en el de desarollo
mer arroja el siguiente error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

y el unico codigo que tengo en php ahi es

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['grupoCom'] as $grupoid => $value): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $grupoid ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

si ese codigo lo cambio por

```
<?php 
    foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='". $grupoid."''>".$value."</option>";
}?>
```

me funciona correctamente. tener en cuenta que de forma local me funciona de cualquiera de las dos maneras.

me imagino que esto sera un asunto de configuración del servidor. 
gracias !

Comment: La forma correcta es la segunda. Esto es incorrecto: `<? endforeach; ?>` ya que te falta una etiqueta de apertura de código PHP: `<?php`... no te acostumbres a las malas prácticas, aunque a veces puedan funcionar.

Comment: disculpa corregire el codigo em ambos los tengo con <?php ?>

Answer (score 1):

No, no creo que sea solamente algo de configuración del servidor.

Veamos:

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['grupoCom'] as $grupoid => $value): ?>
^Abre un bloque PHP                                         ^Cierra el bloque

  <option value="<?php echo $grupoid    ?>">       <?php echo $value ?></option>
                 ^Abre un bloque PHP    ^Cierra    ^Abre             ^Cierra
<? endforeach;           ?>
^**Cierra sin abrir      Cierra de nuevo
```

Para mí escribir código así es una auténtica locura. Particularmente me gusta el orden en el código. Por ejemplo, yo escribiría todo así, sin salir nunca de PHP:

```
<?php 
    $strHTML='<select>'; //Definimos una variable para concatenarle todo a ella
    foreach($_SESSION['grupoCom'] as $grupoid => $value):
        $strHTML.='<option value="'.$grupoid.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    endforeach; 
    $strHTML.='</select>';
    echo $strHTML;
?>
```

O bien así:

```
<?php 
    $strHTML='<select>'; //Definimos una variable para concatenarle todo a ella
    foreach($_SESSION['grupoCom'] as $grupoid => $value) {
        $strHTML.='<option value="'.$grupoid.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $strHTML.='</select>';
    echo $strHTML;
?>
```

Espero no haberme equivocado en alguna comilla. :)

Comment: el <?php endforeach ?> lo tengo cerrado con el php

Comment: el asunto esta en que todo el codigo que no es solamnete eso si no que como 30 archivos lot engo de la otra manera y en el servidor solamente me estan generando error ...

Comment: @WorseMzg por ejemplo aquí te falta un punto y coma de cierre: **`echo $grupoid`**. Si fuera tú, lo iría cambiando poco a poco a un código más organizado, concatenando. Analizar ese tipo de código es un auténtico dolor de cabeza y hace mal a la vista :) Nunca me ha gustado esa mezcla constante de abrir-cerrar, cerrar-abrir... me resulta tedioso.